# calling a Stored Procedure within a IN clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to call a stored procedure within a IN clause?

```
Select field0, field2 FROM Table
WHERE field0 in (exec storedproc)
```

The reason for stored procedure is because of the complexity of it

Comment: @Barry, thank you for formatting

Comment: @DHN, I started out with that, with error message "incorrect syntax near EXEC"

Comment: Well if the the EXEC works without the other stuff around it, then it's not possible to call the stored procedure like that. ;o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have to use [OpenRowset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to achieve this.

```
Select Field0, Field2 From Table
Where Field0 in (
                SELECT Field0 FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
                             'Server=SERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                            'EXEC StoredProc')
                )
```

In order to do this the following options must be enabled on the server:

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

If it isn't possible to change these settings then another option, as discussed with Martin in the comments, is to populate a temporary table.

e.g.

```
declare @t table
(
Field0 int,
Field1 varchar(100)
...
)

Insert Into @t
Exec storedProcedure

Select Field0, Field2 From Table
Where Field0 in (
                SELECT Field0 FROM @t
                )
```

To insert the results of the stored procedure to a temporary table the definition of the temporary table must match the results of the stored procedure exactly.

Comment: +1 This does open a new connection back to the server though.

Comment: @Martin - Yes it does, I can't really think of any other way of doing this? Apart from using Table Functions but I get the impression that the OP doesn't really want to change the SP.

Comment: The OP could also add an intermediate table variable and `INSERT INTO @T EXEC storedproc` then use that in the `IN` clause.

Comment: @Barry, it claims certain security settings for this.

Comment: @Barry, thanks a lot! I was disappointed with those who said that it is not possible to do this. They go after the book, without thinking out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Stored procedure cannot be used for such case. But, review possibility to use table-value function that are correct as argument of IN statment

Comment: +1 re-factoring the stored procedure into a TVF sounds the best solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a stored proc. You need to use a function that returns a table. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunction(@arg varchar(30))
RETURNS @myTable table(Value INT)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into @myTable(Value) values (1)       
    RETURN
END
```

Now you can run the function as part of your query:

```
Select field0, field2 FROM Table
WHERE field0 in (select Value from myFunction('arg'))
```